# What are the wordplays in The Ickabog?

Tags: the-ickabog

JKR is known for her puns in naming things. Harry Potter is full of it.

What are all the puns in her latest installment, The Ickabog?

Answer (score 1):

#### Cornucopia

> a symbol of plenty consisting of a goat's horn overflowing with flowers, fruit, and corn.

#### Spittleworth

> Spittle is "saliva, especially as ejected from the mouth."

#### Chouxville

> Choux pastry, or pâte à choux, is a light pastry dough used in many pastries (particularly cream-filled ones)

#### King Porfirio

Unknown

#### Pluritania

Unknown

#### Kurdsburg

> Curd is a dairy product obtained by coagulating milk in a process called curdling.

#### Fluma

Unknown, but Zulu for "scream"

#### Baronstown

Unknown, possibly through Germany - Baron is German nobility, and Germany is known for sausage.

#### Jeroboam

> A double magnum-sized bottle

#### Bert Beamish

> *“And hast thou slain the Jabberwock? Come to my arms, my beamish boy! O frabjous day! Callooh! Callay!” He chortled in his joy.*

#### Dan Dovetail

> A dovetail joint or simply dovetail is a joinery technique most commonly used in woodworking joinery, including furniture, cabinets, log buildings, and traditional timber framing.

#### Folderol Fancies

> A 'folderol' is a useless ornament or accessory, trifle

#### Cankerby the footman

> Canker sores, also called aphthous ulcers, are small, shallow lesions that develop on the soft tissues in your mouth or at the base of your gums.

#### Marshteazle

Possibly teasel, which looks somewhat like a rat.

#### Gordon Goodfellow

> For He's a Jolly Good Fellow, [celebratory song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_He%27s_a_Jolly_Good_Fellow)

#### Professor Fraudysham

> Fraud is defined as a criminal deception committed by a person who acts in a false and deceitful way.

> A sham is "a thing that is not what it is purported to be."

#### Malik Motley, the artist

> Motley: incongruously varied in appearance or character, disparate; (of clothing) made up of a variety of colours.

#### Tubby Tenderloin (butcher)

> A beef tenderloin, known as an eye fillet in Australasia, filet in France, Filet Mignon in Brazil, and fillet in the United Kingdom and South Africa, is cut from the loin of beef.

#### Private Prodd

> To 'prod' is to "poke with a finger, foot, or pointed object."

#### Ma Grunter

> A grunt is (of an animal, especially a pig) [to] make a low, short guttural sound.

#### Scrumble

A scrumble is small piece of freeform crochet or knitting that can be joined to make a larger piece of freeform work, but I'm not sure of the relevance

---

I think that's all of them. Please add if you find more!

Comment: Jereboam is also the name of a king in the Old Testament that was at war with a neighbor country - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeroboam

Comment: @NKCampbell of course! You can edit it in, as it's a CW.